# How to Join two MS access table of Different Database with common Id in C# in Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am creating a Windows form project where there are two databases. One database contains Bill information other contain Master List of Items. I want to display these two databases in one Datagrid view by joining it with common ID.

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
               
              ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select a.ID, a.Bill_Year, a.Bill_No, a.Voucher_No, a.Date, b.Group_Name from cn.dbo.BillTable AS a INNER JOIN cnlist.dbo.GroupName AS b ON a.Group_ID = b.Group_ID ");

                da.Fill(dt);

                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Here cn and cnlist is OleDbConnection of Database 1 and 2 respectively. BillTable is table name of Database 1 and GroupName is table name of Database 2

Comment: Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, use data adapter to execute the command statement, and then place the query results in the data table, you could try the following code to replace it.

My database1 and database2 file are placed in bin\debug folder.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\WindowsFormsApp19\\bin\\Debug\\DataBase1.mdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cmd.CommandText = "select a.ID, a.Bill_Year, a.Bill_No, a.Voucher_No, a.Date, b.Group_Name, a.Group_ID, b.Group_ID from Database1.mdb.BillTable AS a INNER JOIN Database2.mdb.GroupName AS b ON a.Group_ID = b.Group_ID";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);         
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
```

Result:

[image]