# Error in joining two database tables on same server in C# | Win Form | MS Access

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to join two database tables that are on the same server. Till now I did this - but now I am getting

> Syntax Error in FROM clause

after I use the `IN` clause in this code. I had also tried to make IN clause by directly entering location but that is also not working.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.Tables.Add(dt);

string masterlocation = @"C:\Users\PC\source\repos\Soft\bin\Debug\MasterList.accdb";
string datalocation = @"C:\Users\PC\source\repos\Soft\bin\Debug\billdatabse.accdb";

string scontr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};;Persist Security Info=False;", datalocation);

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(scontr);

string str = string.Format("Select a.ID, b.Group_Name, a.Voucher_No, a.Bill_No, a.Date, c.Vendor_Name, a.Amount FROM (BillTable AS a INNER JOIN GroupName IN '{1}' b ON a.Group_ID = b.Group_ID) INNER JOIN VendorList IN '{1}' c ON a.Vendor_Id = c.Vendor_Id ", datalocation, masterlocation); 

connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(str, connection);

OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

dt.Load(reader);

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

```
Database 1- Master Data
In Database 1 there are two tables
Table 1- GroupName

GROUP_ID   GROUP_Name
1                    Computers
2                    Electricity
....

Table 2- VendorList
Vendor_Id      Vendor_Name
1                     Xyz LTD.
2                     Abc Ltd.
......


Database 2- Bill Database
This database contains one table
Table 1- BillTable
ID.         GROUP_ID       Voucher       Bill_No      Vendor_Id       Amount
1                1.                       32              Db_123           2                  500
2                2                       122              Ss_111          1                  300
3                2                       132              Db_1113        2               1500
4                1                       1224            Ss_21.             1                  3000
......


Required result as
ID.         GROUP_Name   Voucher   Bill_No    Vendor_Name    Amount
1           Computer            32            Db_123        Abc Ltd.         500
2           Electricity           122           Ss_111         Xyz LTD.         300
3           Electricity           132           Db_1113     Abc Ltd.         1500
4            Computer         1224         Ss_21.         Xyz LTD.          3000
......
```

Comment: update your question add  your table schema, a proper data sample and the expected c result  .. as tabular text (not image)

Comment: @scaisEdge See the Update

Comment: Essentially same question (same OP with different username?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719288/how-to-join-two-ms-access-table-of-different-database-with-common-id-in-c-sharp

Comment: No @June7. It different though we have similar problem but I didn't got the answer from that post